# If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed then $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed then $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed? I think the answer is no but I couldn't find a counterexample.

And one more question.  If $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed then $g((X,Y))  h((Y,X))$ are identically distributed  where $g$ , $h$ are random functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? So if that's true then we can get that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X \sim \text{Unif}(\{0,1,2\})$ and $Y=X+1\pmod 3$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are not. For instance, $P((X,Y)=(0,1))=\frac{1}{3}\neq 0 =P((Y,X)=(0,1))$.

I'm not sure I understand your second question. What do you mean by "random functions" $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, and why should $g((X,Y))=h((Y,X))$ for potentially different functions $g,h$?

Comment: I guess there is a simple way to see that $(X,Y)\sim (Y,X)$ implies that the first coordinates $X\sim Y$ even if the asker's last question was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes ,my fault for the = . I mean if (X,Y) and (Y,X) are distributed then for example X+Y and 2X+Y^2 are distributed ? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Are you asking: If $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed, then are $X+Y$ and $2X+Y^2$ identically distributed?

Comment: @kccu yes , is that correct?

Comment: No, they might not even take on the same values. For instance, if $X,Y$ are i.i.d. distributed according to $\text{Unif}(\{0,1\})$, then $X+Y$ takes on the values $0,1,2$, while $2X+Y^2$ takes on the values $0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Well, no. Consider a trivial case where $X=1$ and $Y=1$  a.s., for example. @EvansS.

Comment: yes , thank you . I just want to show that if (X,Y) and (Y,X) is distributed then X and Y is distributed so i thought if something more genneral is true . Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: If you apply the **same** function $f$ to $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$, then this will be true. For instance, erm... the projection to the first coordinate?

Comment: @EvansS. You keep saying "is distributed" where I think you mean "are identically distributed." In any case, as noted in Clement C.'s comment, if $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed, then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed as you wished to show.

Comment: Yes i mean identically distributed, i am sorry.

Comment: i want to prove this so  if A is a Borel then P(f(X,Y)  ∈ A) = P((X,Y)  ∈ f^-1(A))= ( because (X,Y) and (Y,X) identically distributed ) P((Y,X)  ∈ f^-1( A)) = P(f(Y,X)   ∈ A)  , is this solution right? thank you .

Comment: That looks correct to me.